# http GET request based on true or false condition in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

So basically I want to call all the posts when four conditions satisfy.

Initially,

```
a=false,
b=false,
c=false,
d=false
```

When the user selects these options these turn to true

For eg: When user selects `a` then `a=true`

Based on this condition I want to make a http.get request.
Something like this

```
`listAllPosts(a,b,c,d){

GET /posts?a=true }
```

I need to make a GET request based on the condtions everytime one or more than one variable becomes true.

Sorry for bad explaination.

Comment: What is a,b,c,d and all, checkbox/radio button or normal button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially you want a watch expression looking at all four variables. And when that combined expression is 1 ( truthy ) you want to do your ajax call

```
  $scope.a = false;
  $scope.b = false;
  $scope.c = false;
  $scope.d = false;
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.a + $scope.b + $scope.c + $scope.d;
  }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if( newVal === 1 ) {
        console.log('do ajax call here');
    } 
  })
```

Comment: this solution works as well as the first answer. However using checkbox as inidcated above might be enough. This is a little more robust in the sense that if anything changes the properties, then do ajax call.. Only you know what you need.. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The actual problem I am facing is to write the correct $http.get request for this condition. It would be really helpful if you can help me with that.

Comment: sure, so are you trying to build request url correctly or wherein lies the problem?

Comment: #Chris Noring. It was pretty staright forward. I was overcomplicating things. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a, b, c and d are associated with checkboxes. Then you can do the following:

html:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="sendRequest()" ng-model="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="sendRequest()" ng-model="b" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="sendRequest()" ng-model="c" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="sendRequest()" ng-model="d" />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.a = false;
$scope.b = false;
$scope.c = false;
$scope.d = false;

$scope.sendRequest = function () { 
    if ($scope.a || $scope.b || $scope.c || $scope.d ) { 
        // Get request here
    }
}
```

Let me know if issues.

Comment: think you should have OR, || conditions here rather than &&. One or more was the requirement

Comment: @ChrisNoring the question said, "when all the conditions satisfy" therefore i supposed that all should be true in order to process.

Comment: Thanks for commenting i just re read it and edited my answer.

Comment: @HamzaBaig Thanks for your answer.
 I am sorry, I actually need OR over there. For example, if a and b are checked I need a get request which gets all the posts where `a=true` and `b=true`.

Comment: @bumchickbum97 I didn't understand you, please write carefully in english as it becomes ambiguous. You said you need an OR however you wrote "a and b are checked".

Comment: @HamzaBaig Thank you very much for your answer. It worked! I was confused and over complicating things. And sorry for my bad English